# how to insert all elements in a tr zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

i want to add all elements in a tr in my zend form .

currently i am doing is add decorators to each element , 
i wrap the content of the element with a div and then warp it with a td .

like this .

```
    $name->setDecorators(
                         array(
                              array('ViewHelper',
                                        array('helper' => 'formText')
                            ),
                            array('Label',
                                        array('class' => 'label')
                            ),
                            array('HtmlTag',
                                        array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => '')
                            )
                         )
                      );
```

i want to all elements in a tr .

ex:- `<tr> <td>element1</td> <td> element2</td> </tr>`

how can i do this . please help .................. :(

Comment: Have a look at http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450. It shows how to put forms in tables.

Comment: yeah i read it , but it was too complex for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$elementDecorators = array(
    'ViewHelper',
    array(
        array('data' => 'HtmlTag'),
        array('tag' => 'td')
    ),
    array(
        array('openerror' => 'HtmlTag'),
        array('tag' => 'td', 'openOnly' => true, 'placement' => Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract::APPEND)
    ),
    'Errors',
    array(
        array('closeerror' => 'HtmlTag'),
        array('tag' => 'td', 'closeOnly' => true, 'placement' => Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract::APPEND)
    ),
    array('Label',
        array('tag' => 'td')
    ),
    array(
        array('row' => 'HtmlTag'),
        array('tag' => 'tr')
    )
);
```